# covariant type E occurs in contravariant position in type A => returnerror.Error[E,B] of value f

Tags: scala

I have this definition:

```
sealed trait Error[+E, +A] {
  final def map[B](f: A => B): Error[E, B] = {
    this match {
      case Ok(a) => Ok(f(a))
      case Fail(e) => Fail(e)
    }
  }
  final def flatMap[B](f: A => Error[E, B]): Error[E, B] = {
    this match {
      case Ok(a) => f(a)
      case Fail(e) => Fail(e)
    }
  }
}

object Error {
  final case class Ok[A](a: A) extends Error[Nothing, A]
  final case class Fail[E](e: E) extends Error[E, Nothing]
}
```

This won't compile with this error:

```
Error.scala:12: covariant type E occurs in contravariant position in type A => returnerror.Error[E,B] of value f
  final def flatMap[B](f: A => Error[E, B]): Error[E, B] = {
                       ^
one error found
```

I don't get why. Can you, please, explain why this doesn't compile? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will simplify the example a bit in order to make it easier to read.

Imagine you have `trait` like this and let's assume that such declaration is legal:

```
trait Error[+E]  {
  def someMethod (f: String => Error[E])  // actually illegal
}
```

And implementations

```
class ErrorString extends  Error[String]  {

  def someMethod (f: String => Error[String]) = {
    val someVar: Error[String] = f("Somestring")
  }

}

class ErrorInt extends  Error[Int]  {
    ...
}
```

As `E` is covariant we can treat `Error[String]` as subtype of `Error[Any]`, so we can write the follwing

```
val anyError: Error[Any] = new ErrorString()
```

And then pass `String => Error[Int]`  function as a parameter to `someMethod`

```
val intErrorReturnFunction: String => Error[Any] = (k) => new ErrorInt
anyError.someMethod(intErrorReturnFunction) // actually illegal
```

But as `anyError` is still have type `Error[String]` in a background means that we are trying to pass `String => Error[Int]` function to method with `String => Error[String]` parameter.

So at the end we would have something like this

```
 val someVar: Error[String] = f("Somestring"):Error[Int]
```

Comment: _"Error[String] as supertype of Error[Any]"_. I think you mean **subtype** instead of **supertype**, or exchange the order of Errors.